# How encode in a right why emojis using node request module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, telegram-bot, emoji

I'm using **request** module in order to send message to a Telegram bot, everything is fine, except the way I'm display emojis, which don't get printed well

Post request:

```
request.post({
            url: `${this.getApiURL()}/${apiName}`,
            formData: payload,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Charset': 'utf-8',
            }
        }, (err, resp, body) => {});
```

The payload contains a text message with some emojis like:

```
const _emojis = {
            throwingAKiss: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x98',
            tearsOfJoy: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x82',
            smirkingFace: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8F'
        }
```

but I'm displaying this symbol **ð**

Comment: It seems like only your first group is used, as ð is `U+00F0` in UTF8.

Comment: Can you try using this syntax: `"\u{1F604}"`?  ( https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode )

Comment: Also you could try: https://github.com/omnidan/node-emoji

Comment: It worked, thanks. 
It's weird because my code above used to work couple of days ago -_-

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer after your feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround you may have success with using a different unicode notation, i.e.:

```
const smiley = "\u{1F604}";
```

For a list of codes, there are [emoji tables](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) out there.

Additionally, it might ease a bit development overhead by using libraries such as [node-emoji](https://github.com/omnidan/node-emoji) (which uses raw emojis under the hood through [omnidan/node-emoji json file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/omnidan/node-emoji/master/lib/emoji.json).